# how to calculate the number of network days between 2 dates that are always with a fiscal year

Tags: excel-formula

[image]Hi i am looking for some help to see the number of network days between 2 dates and again between a fiscal year on excel@

say for example if the fiscal year starts from april to march
the start date : 1/03/2022 and the end date 30/06/2022

thank you

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the result you expect. By that it is much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help., I think i managed to upload a Jpeg

Comment: and what is your expected result? By the way it is much easier to help you if you provide the sample data and expected result as table within your question --> read [ask], [repro] and use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: So your question is in general: how to calculate the net work days between two dates? In your example they are the start- and end date of a fiscal year. There is a function `NETWORKDAYS` in Excel

Comment: I think I found the formula: is it : =NETWORKDAYS(MAX(fiscal year start date, Employee start date),MIN(employee end date, fiscal year end date)))

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in what you require to be calculated. I couldn't read any min or max values from a range in your question, while that would've made your question more interesting to solve. Ike answered your actual question, while that - in the end - is not what you needed. Expected result(s) with sample data (not screenshots) help.

Answer (score 0):

```
=NETWORKDAYS(MAX(fiscal year start date, Employee start date),MIN(employee end date, fiscal year end date)))
```